# How to start oracle service?

Tags: oracle

I have 3 instance of oracle database which myservice, myservice1, myservice2.
1st database service name is `MYSERVICE;` it's working ok

But I can't start myservice1 and myservice2. How can I start these service?
I am using oracle linux.

```
 tnsping myservice1

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 05-MAY-2020 08:27:48

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
    Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mydatabase.orcl.net)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = myservice1)))
    OK (0 msec)
    [orcl@mydatabase ~]$
    [orcl@mydatabase ~]$ tnsping myservice2

    TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 05-MAY-2020 08:28:02

    Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

    Used parameter files:


    Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
    Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mydatabase.orcl.net)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = myservice2)))
    OK (0 msec)
```

When I trying to connect the db with `SERVICE NAME: myservice1` using SQL developer it says:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor   

Vendor code 12514



select instance_name, status from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NAME    STATUS
---------------- ------------
myservice          OPEN
```

Comment: Your question needs clarifying. First of all, what do you mean by "service". Do you have multiple databases running on the same server ? If so, you need to start them, just like you start "myservice1" - and I assume that is not the real name of your database.

Comment: Or is it that you want multiple services on the same database ? You define multiple services using `DBMS_SERVICE.CREATE_SERVICE()` (as DBA obviously). My question then is "why" ? There is generally no reason to have multiple services on a single database - other than for workload balancing ...

Comment: Or is it that you have a multi tenant environment and each or your service is actually a pluggable database (PDB). Those need starting up too via `alter pluggable database all open` (to start them all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the command:

```
su
"type password"
    reboot
```

....

```
srvctl start database -db myservice1 -startoption mount
srvctl start database -db myservice2 -startoption mount
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the "-startoption mount". Mount state is only for making some configuration changes, backup/recovery operations, and a handful of other administrative functions. Just use this:

```
srvctl start database -db myservice1
srvctl start database -db myservice2
```

Note that "tnsping" won't actually test whether a service is running, only whether the listener is running on the specified hostname and port number from the connection string. You could use any made up service_name and still get an "ok" response as long as the listener is up.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear.

When you use tnsping you actually pass the tnsnames alias (normally the tnsnames alias is the same of the target service name, but it's not a rule)

You can try to start using the package [DBMS_SERVICE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_serv.htm#ARPLS68028), in this package you have the procedure `START_SERVICE`

Syntax:

```
begin
dbms_service.start_service('your_service_name');
end;
/
```

For list the active services in your database query `v$active_services`

To create a service:

```
begin
dbms_service.create_service(service_name=>'your_service',network_name=>'your_service');
end;
/
```

Comment: 'DBMS_SERVICE command not found'

Comment: I gave one example.

Comment: 'ORA-44304: service myservice2 does not exist'

Comment: `lsnrctl status` I don't know how can I explain the problem.
 `Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER

Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "myservice" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "myservice", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "myserviceXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "myservice", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...`

myservice1, myservice2 not listed here, sorry for newbie. I want to start these

Comment: You just have the services myservice and myserviceXDB (created by dispatcher)

Comment: But I had it, where did myservice1, myservice2 gone?

Comment: It seems you has just created a tnsnames alias in tnsnames.ora. When you use the tnsping it actually just test the listener, it not verify if the service exist.

Comment: But I was used these 2 of databases few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 instances (databases) then you need to start them with sqlplus.

```
$ . oraenv
    myservice1
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> startup
```

The same way for the third instance.

Comment: `[orcl@mydatabase ~]$ oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [einorcl] ?

ORACLE_HOME = [/home/oracle] ?

ORACLE_BASE environment variable is not being set since this
information is not available for the current user ID oracle.
You can set ORACLE_BASE manually if it is required.
Resetting ORACLE_BASE to its previous value or ORACLE_HOME
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /u01/app/oracle`

what is the next command `oraenv` ?

Comment: 1. You need to include the dot ( .  oraenv )  as in my example.
2. Set ORACLE_HOME path correctly when asked, it is something like /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1